# Weight conversion in Java

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am supposed to write a program that will do the following:

A weight enthusiast would like a program that allows the user to enter a value in ounces and then displays the combination of tons, pounds, and ounces that each value is maximized in order by tons, pounds, and ounces. The input value should not exceed 500 million ounces (500,000,000).

The output should read as follows:

Enter weight in ounces: 123456789

Combined Number of Tons, Pounds, and Ounces: 
   Tons: 3858
   Pounds: 49
   Ounces: 5
123456789 ounces = 3858 tons + 49 pounds + 5 ounces

I have everything but the ounces working. Im not sure if i set these formulas up right or if there is a better way to do it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class WeightConversion
    {
      public static void main (String[] args)
      { 
         Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

     int weightInOunces = 0;
     int tons = 0;
     int pounds = 0;
     int ounces = 0;

     System.out.print("Enter weight in ounces: ");
     weightInOunces = userInput.nextInt();

     if (weightInOunces > 500000000)
      {  System.out.print("Limit of 500,000,000 ounces exceeded!"); 

      }

     else
     {System.out.println ("Combined Number of Tons, Pounds, Ounces: "
        + "\n\tTons: " + weightInOunces / 32000);
      tons = weightInOunces / 32000;
      System.out.println ("\tPounds: " + (weightInOunces - (tons * 32000)) / 16); 
      pounds = tons / 2000;
      System.out.println("\tOunces: " + ((weightInOunces - (tons * 32000)) - (pounds * 16) ));
      ounces = pounds / 16;
      }   

    }
```

Comment: Compare `pounds = tons / 2000;` with the line above it.

Comment: Try `System.out.println("Switch to metric system!");`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it incrementally, lowest unit first:

```
final int OUNCES_PER_POUND = 16;
final int POUNDS_PER_TON = 2000;

int value = 123456789; // value is in ounces
int ounces = value % OUNCES_PER_POUND;
value /= OUNCES_PER_POUND; // value is now in whole pounds
int pounds = value % POUNDS_PER_TON;
value /= POUNDS_PER_TON; // value is now in whole tons
int tons = value;

// prints: 3858 tons + 49 pounds + 5 ounces
System.out.printf("%d tons + %d pounds + %d ounces%n", tons, pounds, ounces);
```

This is similar to how you often to it for time values:

```
long value = 1472672270262L; // 2016-08-31 19:37:50.262 GMT
long millis  = value % 1000;   value /= 1000;
long seconds = value % 60;     value /= 60;
long minutes = value % 60;     value /= 60;
long hours   = value % 24;     value /= 24;
long days    = value;

// prints: 17044 days + 19 hours + 37 minutes + 50 seconds + 262 millis since Jan 1, 1970 at 00:00 GMT
System.out.printf("%d days + %d hours + %d minutes + %d seconds + %d millis since Jan 1, 1970 at 00:00 GMT%n",
                  days, hours, minutes, seconds, millis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
pounds = tons / 2000;
```

Set pound as:

```
pounds = (weightInOunces - (tons * 32000)) / 16;
```

Also you can remove

```
ounces = pounds / 16;
```

Comment: This worked. I should have saw something that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int tons = weightInOunces / (2000*16);
int remainingOunces = weightInOunces % (2000*16);
int pounds = remainingOunces / 16;
int ounces = remainingOunces % 16;
```